# @FindBy error in class Select (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am trying to  implement **Page Object Factory** in Selenium WebDriver but, when run de code, the Eclipse Show me the following message error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.(Select.java:44)  at
>   page.FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage.preencherCampoMotivo(FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage.java:24)
>     at
>   test.FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest.selecionarFacilidades(FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest.java:38)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

The error occurs in line 23 the class **FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage** and  in line 38 in class **FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest**.

Follow the code of 2 classes and image error.

**FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage**

```
public class FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage {

WebDriver driver;

 @FindBy(id = "cboMotivo") 
 WebElement CBOMotivo;

public FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
public void preencherCampoMotivo(String CampoMotivo) {
    // Campo Motivo
    Select slcMotivo = new Select(CBOMotivo);
    slcMotivo.selectByVisibleText(CampoMotivo); 
}
}
```

**FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest**

```
public class FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest {
static WebDriver driver;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    SelecionarNavegador nav = new SelecionarNavegador();
    driver = nav.iniciarNavegador("chrome", "http://10.5.9.45/BkoMais_Selenium/");
}
@Test
public void selecionarFacilidades() throws Exception {
    // Logando na aplicação
    LogarBkoMaisPage login = new LogarBkoMaisPage(driver);
    login.logar("844502", "Bcc201707");

    // BackOffice >> FaturamentoGe >> Conectividade
    FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesPage menu = new FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesPage(driver);
    menu.logarFaturamentoGeConectividade();

    //Registro >> Novo caso
    RegistroNovoCasoPage reg = new RegistroNovoCasoPage(driver);
    reg.registrarCaso();

    //Preencher campos
    FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage campo = new FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage(driver);
    campo.preencherCampoMotivo(" Concluido ");
}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

[FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFm4V.jpg)

[FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrBGC.jpg)

Comment: Add PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); this to ur object class constructure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullpointerException in Selenium when using SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968344/nullpointerexception-in-selenium-when-using-sendkeys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using PageFactory provided by JAVA however, not initializing it.

There are two places you can initialize it,

**Inside Page Object**

```
public FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

**While Create Page Object**

```
FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage campo = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage.class);
```